# How to prove $\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+...+\frac{1}{2^n}≥1+\frac{n}{2}$

Tags: induction

Okay, I definitely have to use induction
I proved for the base case when $n=1$ and it was easy, but how do I prove when $n=k+1$?

Comment: $$\frac{1}{2^n+1} + \frac{1}{2^n+2} + \frac{1}{2^n+3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \ge \frac{1}{2}$$ because there are $2^n$ terms in that series and each of them is at least $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Comparison_test. This is one of the oldest proofs, given by Oresme in the 14th century.